# Finding a full collision within a large array

Tags: algorithms, arrays, hash

I apologize for the vagueness of the title, but this question is quite difficult for me to describe.
For that reason, I'm unable to directly convey my problem.
In an effort to circumvent this, I've created an example.

> You've been instructed to help style your corporation's new website.
> It's almost done, but you've reached a problem:
> You don't know what color the background should be in.
>
> Unfortunately, the other people in your company are quite opinionated,
> and will only approve of your decision if the color fulfills some unknown,
> predetermined personal bias (e.g. "I like that color because it reminds me of my hometown").
> To make matters worse, your business is extremely large, so the amount of angry emails
> that you'll receive if you goof this up is in the millions.
>
> You can poll your co-workers in order to determine whether or not they like a
> certain color (there are a finite amount of possible colors, though it is quite large), and even measure the exact approval rating for each one.
> The catch is that you can only poll one person at a time, so you can't just bruteforce it.
>
> What method should you use to conjure a color that fulfills the most biases, and in
> the shortest amount of time?

My initial thought was to recursively create a large number of random guesses, and then poll a group of random employees for each one.
The next batch would be composed of random deviations from the highest-scoring guess from the last batch.

For example, if the best answer was 4 and I guessed [3, 7, 9], the next batch might be something like [5, 4, 3].
This works fine on a small scale, but I don't know how it would play out when handling much larger values and sets.

Does anyone know a good algorithm for solving problems like these?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Can you cite your sources?

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material.  Please refer to our guidelines and edit your question accordingly: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @D.W. This isn't copied material. I wrote this myself as a simplification for a much more complex problem. The same goes for the answer I proposed. I clearly explained this within my question. On a side note, this seems irrelevant.

Comment: Got it.  It sounds like I have misunderstood.  You have listed two competing objectives ("minimize time", "minimize complaints").  There is an inherent tradeoff between them and you have not described how the two should be traded off, so the problem is not well-defined/well-posed yet.  I suggest reading about confidence intervals for Bernoulli r.v.'s and about multi-armed bandits.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: If you'd like an answer to the question I suggest you [edit] it to clarify how you will trade off the two metrics you've listed.  Normally you need to specify a single objective function that combines those two metrics in some way to obtain a single objective function; then the problem of minimizing that objective function is well-defined.  Another possible approach is to identify a budget for one of them (e.g., maximum amount of time allowed), and ask for the best possible value of the other metric, within that budget.